# Manifest extra pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I add multiple 'extra' pages that neither run in the background or are content scripts?

Its similar to an options page but not an options page.

I couldn't find anything like in the documentation or I have my terminology mixed up.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

For clarification:

Example pages I would like to show:

- Help page
- Page with a form that interacts with an API
- Page with credits

Comment: If they don't run in the bg or content, where are you using them?

Comment: I want to show it when somebody clicked on a contextmenu.

Comment: Where do you want to show it?

Comment: As a page on its own. When clicked a new tab is opened with the extension page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add those html/css/js files anywhere in the extension and call them like a normal web page. Say they are in the same directory as your `background.js` file, you would grab the url for your help page like this:

```
var helpPageUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('help.html');
```

Then you would use the `tabs` api in your click event for the appropriate context menu action:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: helpPageUrl });
```

Comment: Is it btw possible to call function on the help page? or pass variables to it?

Comment: I haven't tested it but I would imagine you'd be able to send messages similar to passing messages from a content page or popup.

Comment: Yes, you can pass messages.